# View a message while waiting for visitors response on GPS location

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

[image]

I want to show a message while the visitor are deciding if the website will detect current position or not. If website are showing the message as the image above, show a message like "please allow or deny". If clicking on allow, show another message that says "allowed" or something. If denied, show the message "denied" or something. I am using [HTML5 Geolocation](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/).

Is this possible to accomplish and if yes, how can I do this?

Comment: You are not using any php code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this JavaScript snipped.

```
function getLocation(position)
{
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log("Lat: " + lat + " Lng: " + lng);
};

function locate()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported.");
    }
};
```

Now bind the `locate` function where you want it. If you run `locate` the browser will ask you to share your location.

Live-Demo: http://jsbin.com/aKohaVA/1

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't answered my question. Please see my updated question.

Comment: You know how to get the position, now unless you don't have a position show text 'Denied' otherwise you show 'Access'. Where is exactly your problem? Show us some code, that we can see what you want. My Example will ask the user... you can implement you own behavior if the user press allow or not or while he did nothing.

Comment: That's true. But when I click on allow, the message for "on success" will only be visible when my position have been found and Google Maps have been loaded. I want to show a message directly after clicking on allow for the location and when my location have been found and Google Maps have been loaded, I want to replace that message with another message.

Comment: Thanks but that will do exactly like mine - show message on success or fail. Not show message on click on some of these two choices

Comment: OK I know what you mean... You can't do this. The point is this is a specific browser setting so if I configure it to share my position always the box never came up. There is no event or function to cover that. You've to write your own implementation as I described and you already know. Here is a reference, that what you want is not covered http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

Comment: Ok :/ Thanks anyway :)